# Flutter json Unhandled Exception type

Tags: json, flutter, dart

i have a problem with a json response 
Json it's:

```
{
"SData": {
    "total": "1",
    "STable": {
        "year": "2020",
        "S1Lists": [
            {
                "year": "2020",
                "turn": "6",
                "Ranking": [
                    {
                        "position": "1",
                        "Person": {
                            "personId": "paul",
                            "nationality": "none"
                        },
                    },
                   
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Dart code

```
if(response.statusCode == 200){
  final result = response.data;
  Iterable list = result['SData'];
  print(list);
}else{
  throw Exception("Fail!");
}
```

and i receive this error

```
Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<dynamic>'
```

how can i solve if, for example, i want to access the position field or the personId field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your json output is a `Map<String, dynamic>` and not a `Iterable`.

```
if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    final result = response.data;
    final Map<String, dynamic> map = result['SData'];
    print(map );
  } else {
    throw Exception("Fail!");
  }
```

Which will print this output

```
{
   "total":1,
   "STable":{
      "year":2020,
      "S1Lists":[
         {
            "year":2020,
            "turn":6,
            "Ranking":[
               {
                  "position":1,
                  "Person":{
                     "personId":"paul",
                     "nationality":"none"
                  }
               }
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

If you want to get the ranking.

```
  final Map<String, dynamic> data = result ['SData'];
  final Map<String, dynamic> table = data['STable']; // This is like result['SData']['STable']
  final Map<String, dynamic> list = table['S1Lists']; // result['SData']['STable']['S1Lists']
  final Map<String, dynamic> firstItem = list[0]; // result['SData']['STable']['S1Lists'][0]
  final Map<String, dynamic> ranking = list['Ranking']; // result['SData']['STable']['S1Lists'][0]['Ranking']
```

Comment: ok, thanks, it works. But if i want to collect into a variable all the "Ranking" instead of all SData?